# Animate on mouseover an <li> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a .ctp file that looks something like this :

```
<body id="bodyId">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-offset-6" id="header_menuId">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">SignUp</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Search</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    <?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
</body>
```

Now, in this I wanted my li elements to popup little bit every time I scroll my mouse over any of them. However, I have been failing to do so. My jquery code looks like this :

```
$(function () {
    $("#header_menuId").children("li").each(function () {
        $(this).mouseover(function () {
            ($this).animate({
                height: '+=150px',
                width: '+=150px'
            });
        });
    });
});
```

It  doesn't seem to work anyway I try it. Since, I am new to CakePHP and JQuery, may be I am missing some thing here. I tried using mouseenter() as well instead of mouseover(). The .js file is properly connected with my view. I checked it by creating a simple function that I called on mouse click on a particular element.

Comment: `($this)` to `$(this)`

Comment: Doesn't work. Corrected that mistake.

Comment: @Siddhant Can you please create jsfiddle

Comment: Also there is no need of `each()`

Comment: This is not a cakephp issue. This is only css or jquery issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS [**transitions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition) with `:hover` to scale the anchor which is currently hovered.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/tgsvrttL/)

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transform: scale(1);
}
a:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Login</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">SignUp</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Search</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

If you *still* want to use jQuery, you can use `hover` with `animate` to animate the fontsize.

```js
// On hover of li
$("#header_menuId li").hover(function() {

  // Stop previous animation and increase the fontsize
  $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
    fontSize: '+=15px'
  });
}, function() {
  // Stop previous animation and decrease the fontsize
  $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
    fontSize: '-=15px'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-offset-6" id="header_menuId">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">SignUp</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Search</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If I'd be doing this using jQuery, I'd have used `$(document).on('mouseover', '#header_menuId li', function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '+=150px',
        width: '+=150px'
    });
});`

Comment: It works the way you said using css perfectly, however, it doesn't seem to work when I try using jquery. Tried all the jquery snippets posted here.

Comment: @Siddhant Did you try the code in above comment? Please create [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) demo

Comment: @Siddhant Please check [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/szjekps8/), is this you want?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. I am checking if there is any other issue with my code. since it seems to work with the jquery snipper that you posted earlier on jsfddle and it works with the css changes that you posted as wel..

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an mistake in your code:

```
$(function() {
$("#header_menuId").children("li").each(function(){
    $(this).mouseover(function(){ 
        ($this).animate({ // <------- Here, change to $(this)
            height: '+=150px',
            width: '+=150px'
        });
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/gr6h0fm3/)**

Use `.find` instead of `.children` as `li` ins't direct `child` of the `#header_menuId` and also change `($this)` to `$(this)`

```
$("#header_menuId").find("li").each(function(){
    $(this).mouseover(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            height: '+=150px',
            width: '+=150px'
        });
    });
});
```

Well you can also use `.on` - `mouseover` and directly bind the event to `li` as below:

```
$("#header_menuId li").on('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).animate({
        height: '+=150px',
        width: '+=150px'
    });
}).on('mouseout',function(){
    $(this).animate({
        height: '-=150px',
        width: '-=150px'
});
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/gr6h0fm3/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this by using hover, am attached hover handler directly into `li` element then no need for each function in this case :

```
$("#header_menuId li").hover(function () {
   $(this).stop().animate({ // mouseenter
     height: '+=150px',
     width: '+=150px'
   });
 }, function () {
   $(this).stop().animate({ // mouseleave
    height: '-=150px',
    width: '-=150px'
   });

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/ejezmenb/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(function() {
  $("li").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      height: '+=150px',
      width: '+=150px'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="bodyId">
  <div id="header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-offset-6" id="header_menuId">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Login</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">SignUp</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Search</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
  <?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?></body>
```